# How to solve PHP Fatal error: Class 'COM' Error? I can't access php.ini in the webhost but it's working offline in WAMP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, com, sms

I'm running my first website online using hostinger.ph free web hosting. I'm having an error saying:

```
Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in /home/u527002491/public_html/map.php on line 59  
[13-Sep-2016 09:45:18] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/u527002491/public_html/centralhomepage.php on line 79  
[13-Sep-2016 09:50:19]
```

I need it to work for my SMS notification.  I searched the web for hours and can only see answers about changing something in the php.ini but it's impossible to change that in hostinger.php.

I also found out about changing or adding something in the .htaccess file but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: What's the _full_ error.

Comment: Fatal error:  Class 'COM' not found in /home/u527002491/public_html/map.php on line 59
[13-Sep-2016 09:45:18] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/u527002491/public_html/centralhomepage.php on line 79
[13-Sep-2016 09:50:19]

Comment: Welcome, go through some tips to make you question clearer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please see http://php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php

Comment: I read that already, but my problem is that I can't access php.ini in hostinger.ph. My website is working in the localhost but having a problem online.

Comment: Then you need to talk to them. You can't use that class if the extension is not installed on the server.

Comment: Maybe it's about time to find another webhosting site than to get stuck in this forever. Btw, thank you for your help. I don't know how to contact them but maybe it would be easier to find another. Regards, @JonStirling

Comment: If you want to be able to install your own extensions, you may need a VPS.